# Inheritance Object method in IE

Tags: javascript

I've defined method fadeIn for Object

```
Object.prototype.fadeIn = function(d, callback) { //some code here };

....

var b = documentGetElementById('b1'); // <div id="b1"></div>
b.fadeIn();
```

It works in FF, Opera, Chrome, but IE reports "Object doesn't support this property or method" when I try launch fadeIn. Why IE doesn't inherit my methods from Object and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In IE, DOM nodes do not inherit from `Object.prototype`. They're not obliged to; as host objects (i.e. objects provided by the environment) they can essentially do what they like. I recommend reading [Juriy Zaytsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax)'s [excellent article about extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

The simple solution is to write a function that accepts an element as parameter:

```
function fadeIn(el, d, callback) {
    // Implementation code
}

var b = document.getElementById('b1');
fadeIn(b);
```